# How to use email for login in django rest?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, authentication

This is my serializer for login view
when I'm trying to use email for login it returns None (it can't take users' email)!
but with the username, everything is ok
anyone can help me to find what is the problem?

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user_email = authenticate(**data)
        print(user_email)
        print('this is serializer print')
        if user_email and user_email.is_active:
            return user_email
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")
```

this is my login view

```py
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        print(user)
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```